# Django Rest Framework: How to request data validate before serializers?

Tags: python, django

I want to validate email variable before UserSerializer, and then return filtered data. The following code works; but I declared "serializer" twice. If I want to use serializer once, how can I do it?

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        Users = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        serializer = UserSerializer(Users, many= True)

        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data})
    else:
        return Response({"status": "errors", "data": serializer.errors})
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    sex = ChoiceField(required=False, choices=User.TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone', 'name','sex', 'updated', 'created')
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'men'),
        ('1', 'girl'),
        ('2', 'nobody'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    phone = models.TextField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    name = models.TextField(default="AKA")
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
        default="0"
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

Comment: Why do you need to validate the email? If `request.data.get('email')` is not valid, then the filter will definitely not return any user since, well, these should only contain valid email adresses.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  If no  enter email  parameter, I want to send back a verification prompt message

Comment: Use another serializer for validating email

Answer (score 0):

User anether serializer for Validating Email

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
```

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user(request):
    
    serializer = EmailSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        Users = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        serializer = UserSerializer(Users, many= True)

        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data})
    else:
        return Response({"status": "errors", "data": serializer.errors})
```

Comment: if I want to in UserSerializer to  validating email  and  filter data, Is there a better way?  or generally don't do it ,